# RLS feature not working for 1 table and only for 1 customer

Tags: ssas-tabular

We have setup RLS in our organization and 1 tabular model is used for all the customer.
Issue which I am facing now is only for 1 customer 1 of the tables in tabular model showing blank when applying RLS.

For eg:
When calling the REST API call in the application it comes up blank.
[image]

This is in Power BI

[image]

Source for both the reports is Azure Analysis Service.

Measure for the Order Column :

Orders:= COUNTROWS( VALUES( OrderDetail[OrderKey] ) )

Same report is running for other customer without any problem, and issue is happening only for 1 table, I have tried with other tables and there is no issue.

Can anyone please help with this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

I always start debugging RLS problems by checking the ID being used. 95%+ of the time the ID isn't what we are expecting or has problems in Azure Active Directory. In all my RLS reports, I have a measure `UPN = USERPRINCIPALNAME( )`, and this is somewhere in the report so I can see what's being used and start troubleshooting from there. If you can't confirm the ID, you are just guessing.

Next use the [View as...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#validate-the-roles-within-power-bi-desktop) option from Power BI Desktop and [Test as role...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#validating-the-role-within-the-power-bi-service) from the Power BI Service to see if you can duplicate the problem. If the data isn't showing, check your security table and RLS rules.

Finally, if all that checks out, use [funnel icon on the visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-report-filter#view-filters-applied-to-a-visual) to see the filters applied to the visual. It could be that some other active filter is removing the data besides RLS.

Then if the data is still filtered, check if you have multiple RLS filters, then remove them one by one and check if your data appears. I just helped someone who filtered 2 fact tables in his Role filters, but both fact tables had bi-directional connections with a common fact table. Fact table 1 had no rows, it would filter the dimension table, which would then filter the second fact table in the visual and filter out those rows. The solution here was to use RLS to filter the dimension table and change the bi-directional connections to single direction from dimension to fact table.